# How do I flush a conditioned control's value if the parent control has been unchecked?

Tags: theme-customizer

I have two controls, one of which depends on another to show up:

```
   $wp_customize->add_section(
        'woo_enchancements',
        [
            'title' => __( 'WooCommerce Enchancements', '_amnth' ),
            'priority' => 32,
            'active_callback' => 'is_woocommerce_active',
            'description' => 'Must refresh the page after tweaking settings to see effects.'
    ]
);

$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'load_woo_custom_functionality',
    [
        'default' => '0',
        'transport' => 'refresh'
    ]
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'load_woo_custom_functionality_control',
        [
            'label'  => __( 'Load up Woo Enchancements?', '_amnth' ),
            'section' => 'woo_enchancements',
            'settings' => 'load_woo_custom_functionality',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
        ]
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'display_woo_header',
    [
        'default' => '0',
        'transport' => 'refresh'
    ]
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'display_woo_header_control',
        [
            'label'  => __( 'Display Woo Header?', '_amnth' ),
            'section' => 'woo_enchancements',
            'settings' => 'display_woo_header',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'active_callback' => 'is_woocommerce_enchanced'
        ]
    )
);
```

`display_header` depends on `load_woo_custom_functionality` to load, **but when I set the value of** `display_header` and I uncheck `load_woo_custom_functionality`, the value still remains when it should default to what is default for it - in this case, `0`.

Here's an illustration of what happens:

[image: Customizer not flushing conditioned controls values]

It doesn't. How can I make sure this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I later found out that, indeed, the values are flushed, **but you can only see the effect after you've closed the customizer (a refresh).**

There's no need for any flushing functionality.